# Why does Acid Splash last one round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Why does the cantrip Acid Splash indicate it lasts one round?  My understanding is the spell does 1d3 points of damage if it hits a target and no further damage or effects happen.  Is there an additional effect noted elsewhere I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spell is of the Conjuration school, so it conjures a ball of acid and fires it at an enemy, after which it disappears once a round has passed. It doesn't deal damage more than once.

The conjuration school normally summons effects that last for longer than a round, such as conjuring a magic sword, magical creatures, or other effects, so its important for a conjuration spell to stipulate if it lasts longer.

Comment: Okay, so it signifies it is creating an object and that the object expires in one round?  That makes sense.

Comment: @MadMAxJr Worth noting: a duration of Instantaneous (which is the typical choice for a nuke spell) on a Conjuration (Creation) spell implies that the created substance lasts indefinitely (because the magic spell creates a non-magical substance that, once created, persists). This 1-round duration effectively prevents any attempt to horde the created acid for any purpose.

Comment: @KRyan That would make a great answer.